# Photos get stuck in iPhone email outbox

Tags: iphone, email, photos, photos.app

Whenever I email a photo from the iPhone 4 photo app then the email gets *stuck* in the **Outbox**.  Just doing a refresh leaves it there, even when viewing the outbox.  To get them to send I manually need to open each email in the outbox and hit send again (and again specifying what size to make the image).

Is there a way to make the photos send automatically, or to at least send them all at once?  Manually sending each one at time is tedious.  The first few times I discovered this I had quite a few emails to send out (some of them more than a month old).

Update: I am sending them from the standard photo app when they get stuck. Then resending them from the standard mail app. The size doesn't seem to matter (small, medium, large or original).  Neither does WiFi or 3G.

Comment: Are you sending these from Apple's standard Mail app, another app, or a web browser? Also, what are the file sizes of these photos?

Comment: Sending them from the standard photo app when they get stuck.  Then resend them from the standard mail app.  The size doesn't seem to matter (small, medium, large or original).

Comment: Can you send other attachments?

Comment: @Kyle: When I make the attachment from the mail app then it sends fine.  I can't think of another app that sends mail with attachments to test with.

Comment: the only one I can think of at the top if my head is voice memos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed itself when I updated to latest version of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I still had the same problem in iOS 6!

For historical reasons I had two accounts syncing with GMail. One for the contacts and one for Mail/Calendar. As soon as I reduced it to one account the mails were sent immediately.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! On this site, you can edit your answers after posting them (as can others, BTW), so adding details and clarifications is easily done in the answer itself.